# Availability of Video-Tag

Tags: html, video, cross-browser, html5-video

I used HTML's own `video` tag instead of the "old" `flash` way to display a video on my own site:

```
<video src="video.mp4" preload="auto" autobuffer controls autoplay>
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/123456" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</video>
```

I tested it on my own computer with 3 different browsers: Chrome (30), Firefox (24) and IE (10). It worked as expected.
Then I asked another user to test my site on different machines with different browsers. Unfortunately it didn't work on all machines, even though he used the same browser versions like me.
Firefox displayed him the following error: `Video format or MIME type is not supported`.

- How is it possible, that the same browsers behave different on
  different machines?
- Why didn't Firefox display the alternative
  content, in my case the `vimeo` video in the iframe?
- Is there a way to ensure and check that my videos will be displayed
  in all browsers on all machines?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox has no native MP4/H.264 support, it uses the codec available on the system for this, and in case there is no proper H.264 codec, the video won't play, and you'll receive that error message.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Supported_video_formats

The fallback content is only used in case the browser doesn't understand the `video` element at all, unsupported codecs won't cause the fallback to be used.

In order to make sure the video plays in all major browsers, irrespective of the OS, you have to supply the video in different formats using the `source` element.

Currently using WEBM VP8/9, OGG Theora and MP4 H.264 should do it.

```
<video preload="auto" autobuffer controls autoplay>
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/123456" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</video>
```

You could also try utilizing the [`error` event](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-error) on the `video` element or on the last `source` element, and implement a JavaScript based fallback where you replace the `video` element with its content.

Example from the W3 specs:

```
<script>
 function fallback(video) {
   // replace <video> with its contents
   while (video.hasChildNodes()) {
     if (video.firstChild instanceof HTMLSourceElement)
       video.removeChild(video.firstChild);
     else
       video.parentNode.insertBefore(video.firstChild, video);
   }
   video.parentNode.removeChild(video);
 }
</script>
<video controls autoplay>
 <source src='video.mp4' type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
 <source src='video.ogv' type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'
         onerror="fallback(parentNode)">
 ...
</video>
```

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#source-default-media

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where the difference between *.ogg and *.ogv is? I thought ogg ist audio and ogv is video but this site: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) suggests to use ogg as a video format.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, `.ogg` was used as the generic extension for all OGG container content. The `.ogv` extension was created for OGG containers with video content (and `.oga` for audio), and the developers ([Xiph.Org](http://xiph.org/)) do now [recommend to use it instead of `.ogg`](http://wiki.xiph.org/index.php/MIME_Types_and_File_Extensions). I'll update my answer. btw, you shouldn't rely too much on information from w3schools: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: So even if the file extension is `ogv`, the type still remains `video/ogg`?

Comment: Yep, it remains `video/ogg`. And for `.ogg` extensions it would now be `audio/ogg`, just like for `.oga`.